# Change color of a String Interpolation within a text object in flutter

Tags: flutter

Hi all I am trying to figure out how to make the Strings inside of my appBar title Text object different colors then the default white, while leaving the word BALLS : in white. $ballcount should be red and $showBallCount should be orange.

Your input is appreciated

```
appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
    title: Text('BALLS : $ballCount $showBallsCalled'),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try the RichText widget.

```dart
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
        title: RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
            text: 'BALLS: ',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            children: [
              TextSpan(
                text: '$ballCount ',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ),
              TextSpan(
                text: '$showBallsCalled',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.orange,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: tyvm that worked great and I learned something new